# select non-existing pairs of ids in one MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, select

I have a set of ids in a table (column id), lets say from 1-10, I want to couple.

I have an existing set of completely randomly generated couples in a table (columns id1, id2).

I want to find the set of remaining couples on a single SQL statement.

It's very easy for permutations, my problem is with combinations without repetition. That means when considering (id1,id2) == (id2,id1) or in other words I don't know how to do to find a set which doesn't include the existing couples with the order changed.

Any ideas?

E.g. If i have table myids

```
|id|
|1 |
|2 |
|3 |
|4 |
|5 |
|6 |
|7 |
|8 |
|9 |
|10|
```

and table mycouples

```
|id1|id2|
|1  |2  |
|9  |1  |
|7  |8  |
```

I should get 10*9 - 6 = 84 different couples with my statement, that is all posible permutations of 10 elements not including (id1=1,id2=2),(id1=2,id2=1),(id1=9,id2=1),(id1=1,id2=9),(id1=7,id2=8),(id1=8,id2=7).

Comment: Not sure, what are you trying to get, but `RIGHT JOIN` + `WHERE some_id IS NULL` may help you.

Comment: Yes, very confusing question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Tried to clarify, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    m1.id AS id1
  , m2.id AS id2
FROM myids AS m1
  JOIN myids AS m2
    ON m1.id <> m2.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM mycouples AS c
        WHERE (c.id1, c.id2) = (m1.id, m2.id)
      )
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM mycouples AS c
        WHERE (c.id2, c.id1) = (m1.id, m2.id)
      )
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is more elegant than mine (And I guess more efficient too). I really hated how little my `WHERE assoc.id1 IS NULL´ clause was saying about what I was doing, I will use this instead.

Comment: The `WHERE NOT EXISTS subquery` can be rewritten with a `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`. You can try different versions to see which has better performance if this this is a query that needs to be run often.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT perids.* FROM (SELECT myids1.id AS id1, myids2.id AS id2 
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM myids) AS myids1  
            INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM myids) AS myids2 
            ON myids1.id <> myids2.id) AS perids 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ((SELECT id1,id2 FROM mycouples)UNION ALL(SELECT id2,id1 FROM mycouples)) 
        AS assoc USING (id1,id2) 
        WHERE assoc.id1 is NULL;
```

seems to do the trick... (wasn't easy to think of it though ^^')